# Inter thread communication in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, message-queue

From the main of my program I am launching to threads (A and B). Thread_A is in charge of generating blocks of a signal (it stores theses blocks in a matrix visible for both threads), whereas Thread_B is responsible for its transmission.

My goal is that each time thread_A generates a block, it has to notify thread_B for its transmission (maybe a good approach would be to send the address of the memmory blocks filled). For this purpose, I thougth to use POSIX message queues, but unfortunately I have no experience with this kind of stuff.

Can anybody provide me a simple example of inter thread communication applicable for this scenario?

Comment: Maybe look up "producer/consumer" for some examples.

Comment: you can check the condition variables. see <condition_variable>. check this:  http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable. It's notify_one() or notify_all() methods should suit your needs. It's purpose is to notify other threads if some condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Intel's *"Threading Building Blocks"* offer a concurrent queue which works really well. Not sure if you are referring to POSIX Message Queues or System V Message Queues or some Windows-y stuff, but note that macOS doesn't support both types if a Mac port may be down the line somewhere. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506081

Answer (score 3):

Here some example with using condition variable. One thread generates signals. The other one transmits them. The signals in this example are just int's. There is also a sleep there to simulate some load. Hope this helps:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

bool rdy_flg;
mutex rdy_mtx;
condition_variable rdy_cond_var;

bool finished;

vector<int> my_signals;

void GenerateSignals() {

    const int kNumOfTests = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < kNumOfTests; ++i) {

        // 1. for each test generate some random signals - just int's in this case
        int n = rand() % 11;
        if (n == 0) n = 5;
        vector<int> vec(n);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) vec[j] = rand() % 1000;

        {
            // 2. now we are updating the global variable
            // -> need to lock here
            lock_guard<mutex> lg(rdy_mtx);
            my_signals = vec;
            cout  << "Generating signals: ";
            for (auto& v : my_signals) cout << v << " ";
            cout << endl;
            rdy_flg = true;

           // if last test -> set finished to true for other thread
           // to know to not wait for new notifications any more
           if (i == kNumOfTests-1)
              finished = true;



        }  // 3. lock guard goes out of scope -> automatic unlock 

        // 4. send notification to the other thread
        rdy_cond_var.notify_one();



        // 5. simulate some heavy work
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void TransmitSignals() {

    while (!finished) {
        // need unique lock here
        unique_lock<mutex> ul(rdy_mtx);

        // wait for notification until rdy_flg is true - there is something to read
        rdy_cond_var.wait(ul, [] { return rdy_flg; });
        cout << "Transmitting signals: ";
        for (auto& v : my_signals) cout << v << " ";
        cout << endl;

        // reset rdy_flg to false for not to process the same signals again
        rdy_flg = false;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));

    auto f1 = async(launch::async, GenerateSignals);
    auto f2 = async(launch::async, TransmitSignals);
}
```

Here the live example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/hgoZB8POiWAYEZ5I

Here the updating example with processing the same signal repeatly :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

mutex mtx_signals;
mutex mtx_cout;
bool finished;

vector<int> my_signals;

void GenerateSignals() {
  const int kNumOfTests = 3;

  for (int i = 0; i <= kNumOfTests; ++i) {
    int n = rand() % 11;
    if (n == 0) n = 5;
    vector<int> vec(n);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) vec[j] = rand() % 1000;

    if (!finished) {
      {
        lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_signals);
        my_signals = vec;
        if (i >= kNumOfTests) finished = true;
      }
      if (!finished) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lgcout(mtx_cout);
        cout << "Generating signals: ";
        for (auto& v : my_signals) cout << v << " ";
        cout << endl;
      }
    }

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
  }
}

void TransmitSignals() {
  while (!finished) {
    vector<int> sigs;
    {
      lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx_signals);
      sigs = my_signals;
    }
    if (sigs.size()) {
      lock_guard<mutex> lgcout(mtx_cout);
      cout << "Transmitting signals: ";
      for (auto& v : sigs) cout << v << " ";
      cout << endl;
    }
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
  }
}

int main() {
  srand(time(nullptr));

  auto f1 = async(launch::async, GenerateSignals);
  auto f2 = async(launch::async, TransmitSignals);
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/R7DdsdItqJX0L07k

Comment: I think you have a race condition on the variable `finished`. `TransmitSignals` may test it, find it false and start waiting for a new notification when there are no more notifications coming.

Comment: @StPiere this is an interesting approach, thank you so much! But imagine that inside the TransmitSignals function I want to send continiously the same signal until I receive a new one. With this condition variable it will be impossible :S

Comment: @Mark Setchell: yeah, thanks. I moved setting finished to true inside the first lock - so it's set before every new notification. I think this should work.

Comment: @anatoly: I just added one more example regarding to your comment.